# The query limit on the Places API web service is different from the JS limit

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I was developing an application which uses the places API through the Javascript Library (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places), and although I was making hundreds of searches with it at any given time, I never seemed to go over the limit.

I've decided to move the search aspect of my application to the server-side, though, because I was developing a mobile version and didn't want mobile browsers doing 100+ requests at a time. So, I switched to using the Web Service API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/)

In doing so I seem to be going over the query limit all of a sudden. What is the reason for this? Is there any way I can solve this without having to increase my query limit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that using the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 you are limited [with this policy](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage)
and by using the Google Places API you have [these limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#Limits).I think you should go through [verification](https://developers.google.com/places/usage) so you raise the limit from 1000 to 100000

Comment: The Google Places API has no price though, right? I won't be billed by going anywhere near that limit?

Comment: Correct, there is currently no price or billing for the Places API.

Comment: @Argiropoulos  Can you tell the verification steps or any link..thanx