# Google Places API Maximum Limit for TextSerach

Tags: ios, google-places-api

The maximum allowed queries for google places text search api is 100 per day...
is it for a individual device(phone) or for the key ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Google places [Usage limit](https://developers.google.com/places/policies#usage_limits) link. It says 1000 req in 24 hrs per api key.

Also if you are checking between google maps and google places api [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863976/the-query-limit-on-the-places-api-web-service-is-different-from-the-js-limit) might help.

Answer (score 0):

It's for the Key.

Please check [Google API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/places/policies#usage_limits)